# Error Parsing XML not well formed

Tags: android, xml

This is probably a simple question but I have looked around and tried fixing my code to no avail. I get the Parsing XML not well formed error on the line:

```
android:text="@string/button_string"
```

My strings.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">PracticeApp</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="button_string">i</string>
    <string name="aldo">aldo</string>
    <string name="GRA">GRA</string>
    <string name="AME">AME</string>
    <string name="cush">cush</string>
    <string name="conn">conn</string>
    <string name="menu">menu</string>     
</resources>
```

And my activity_main file is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_width="50sp"
             android:layout_height="50sp"
             android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
             android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
             android:background="@drawable/round_button"
             android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
             android:text="@string/button_string"
             android:textColor="#fff" />

...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/help fixing this problem.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? I don't see anything obviously wrong here.

Comment: Yeah I have tried cleaning and restarting eclipse but the error is still showing up. Also, thanks for fixing the formatting.

Comment: there is a `...` in the relative layout of activity_main.  If that is actually there in the code, that would cause the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, close the file and open it again, sometimes a " or < remains invisible for some reason and errors like this one happens. Other than that, I see nothing else wrong at this moment.

Comment: Thanks apparently it was something that because I copied and pasted "android:text=" something got copied along with it and when I retyped it by hand it started working. What a waste of an hour haha.

Comment: It might look silly but it can really drive you crazy if you don't know something like that can happen. Glad you fixed it.